# Find all polynomials $p $ satisfying $p(x+1)=p(x)+2x+1. $

Tags: polynomials

Find all polynomials  $p $ satisfying $p(x+1)=p(x)+2x+1. $

I found this on a local question paper, and I am unable to solve it.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: By an easy induction $p(n)=n^2+k$, were $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $k$ is a constant. Suppose $p(x)$ was a polynomial of degree $n$. Then it would match $x^2+k$ on more than $n+1$ values.

Answer (score 0):

Given $p(x+1)-p(x) = 2x+1,$ Means $p(x) = ax^2+bx+c$

So $$a(x+1)^2+b(x+1)+c-\left[ax^2+bx+c\right] = 2x+1$$

So $2ax+a+b = 2x+1,$ Means $a=1$ and $b=0$

So we get $p(x) = x^2+c$

Comment: Omits the core of the proof, which is why the degree of any solution must be at most 2.